# change the type of a column in a view?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a view test with the column year( int) and ID (int)

I want to change every value in the year column into a string and concatenate " 's" to every value in the column. How would be the best way to go about this? I've tried altering my views but it never works for some reason.

```
alter test alter column year varchar(11)
```

Sorry i'm new to sql and been trying to look up how to do this for a while and can't find a definite answer to this.

Comment: If it's truly then a view then I presume that MySQL is just like every other database platform. You need to alter the query with an expressions that casts the year and concatenates the `'s` string. But you can't apply `alter table` to a view.

Comment: why to change the table schema. when you can do it at view level with `convert` or `cast`.

Comment: `concat(cast(year as nvarchar(50)),''s')` will do the trick at view level

Comment: how do i specify what view to use that expression for?

Comment: post your sql for `view`

Comment: my view is:  create view test as select * from table; (this has columns year and ID both integers)  Then i did select concat(cast(year as nvarchar(50)), ''s') from test; and now it won't do anything.. no matter what i type no action gets preformed. I should mention that i'm using postgres

Comment: @user125535  Question tagged with MySQL and you are using Postgres to test ?

Comment: yes i am is that a problem?

Comment: how come when i do select concat(year, 's') from q4b; it returns: 1970____s ? (the underline is whitespace) why is there so much space between the two strings?

Comment: @user125535 `MySQL` and `Postgres` are two different providers so syntax differ for both . `concat` is mysql specific function and I dont know will it work in `Postgres` or not

Answer (score 0):

Syntax to change column name in MySql:

`alter table table_name change old_column_name new_column_name data_type(size)`;

Comment: How is that relevant for the OP's question?